# Exception with message not found error due to <i> tag

Tags: php, dom

So I'm using a code to get information from a site `gatherer.wizards.com`.
And in this information I need to replace the images with a text, it was going well, until in some cards the image appears inside a `<i>` tag.

Here is the code I've being using:

```
$textDiv = $xpath->query('...');

$text = '';
foreach ($textDiv as $textPart)
{
    $l = $textPart->getElementsByTagName('img')->length;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++)
    {
        $search  = array('/Handlers/Image.ashx?size=small&name=','&type=symbol');
        $replace = array('{','}');
        $src = str_replace($search, $replace, $textPart->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src'));
        $newNode = $doc->createTextNode($src);
        $textPart->replaceChild($newNode, $textPart->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0));
    }
    $text .= $textPart->textContent."\n";
```

It is working as I needed it to, for the majority of the cards. But every time a card has an image inside a `<i>` (that is the only one I encountered so far), I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error' in ...php:60 Stack trace: #0 ...php(60): DOMNode->replaceChild(Object(DOMText), Object(DOMElement));

Line 60 being the line where I use the `replaceChild`.

I've searched and found people saying that using `$textPart->nodeParent->replaceChild` would solve this, but it's not the case for me.

Ty for anyone who can help, if you guys need anymore information let me know.

This link is a card where the code work:

```
http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=2
```

This link is a card where the code don't work:

```
http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370618
```

I checked several cards, and the ones with the problem are always the ones with the `<i>` tag.

Comment: Why are you scraping a site? This is generally considered bad practice, and if the site has a ToS I'm pretty sure it's not allowed.

Comment: I'm creating a database of all MTG cards, and from what I found on wizards terms of use, it's ok.

2. Intellectual Property Ownership; Rights Granted to You
The text, images[...], available through the Site (collectively, "Site Content") are the proprietary property of Wizards or its licensors or other Users, and are protected by copyright, trademark, and other intellectual property laws. You are granted a limited, non-sublicenseable license to access and use the Site and electronically copy (except where specified as prohibited)

Comment: if you keep reading it states the non commercial use and such, and in the gatherer section, there is noting saying that copy of that part is prohibited

Comment: Can you tell me more exactly where is the <i> inside the image? The only italic tag I've see was from Flavor text is that it? From your code it seems you're grabbing the image alone so I am out of the loop.

Comment: In the card act of treason there is the last part: (It can attack and Tap this turn.) in italic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$textPart->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)` is not a direct child of `$textPart` in this case (it's a grandchild or even further down). You can fix this without bothering to much about the actual layout with the fact that [every DOMNode has a `->parentNode` property](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.parentnode):

```
$node = $textPart->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);
$node->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $node);
```

... which also brings you the added advantage of only having to call `getElementsByTagName()->item(0)` once per loop.

Comment: Thanks, it works! just a question, when accessing it as `$textPart->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)` it looks to me like I'm missing some thing and then I'm using a "hack" to get where I want, is there a way to improve this? if it's relevant the query I omitted in the original post is `'//div[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_SubContent_SubContent_textRow"]/div[@class="value"]/div[@class="cardtextbox"]'`

Comment: Hm, I see, as you are _deleting_ nodes, just calling `$node = $imgcollection->item(0);` would suffice. With the current setup (omitting the `$textPart->getElementsByTagName('img')`), but your XPath could be altered to: `'//div[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_SubContent_SubContent_textRow"]/div[@‌​class="value"]/div[@class="cardtextbox"]//img` to prevent even 1 call to `getElementsByTagName()`.

Comment: but if I used this XPath, I would need a second Xpath to get the text right? guess I will try it and measure the time used with each method to get the fastest code, ty again

Comment: @vtFurlin: ah yes, if you want the text, yes... You could however just replace all the images, and get the resulting text then. Either way, `->getElementsBTagName()` will be called 0 or 1 times, not multiples ;)